# How do you test a expressApp.post()?

Tags: node.js, express, dialogflow-es

I a C# developer trying to learn node.js / Dialogflow on the fly.  I am trying to create a webhook in node.js on Azure that I would use as a fulfillment for my Dialogflow project.

My understanding is that I need to convert the following

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);

to

expressApp.post( '/dialogflowFulfillment', (request, response) => {
}

```
'use strict';
var debug = require('debug');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

app.post('/dialogflowFulfillment', function (req, res) {
  res.send('POST request to homepage');
});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

My question is how do I test the 'expressApp.post()' so I know its getting called.  I used Visual Studio 2017 and created a blank node.js express app then I added the post function.  I run app and then use the Postman app to send a post request to the url (localhost:3000)/dialogflowFulfillment but I get a 404 error.

What am I missing?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: can you share full code?

Comment: My bad.  I updated the question with the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to move your function above the error handling:

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// Put your function right here
app.post('/dialogflowFulfillment', function (req, res) {
  res.send('POST request to homepage');
});

// Catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});
```

The function to catch `404` and forward to error handling does the following as described [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html):

> Calls to `next()` and `next(err)` indicate that the current handler is
>   complete and in what state. **`next(err)` will skip all remaining
>   handlers in the chain except for those that are set up to handle
>   errors as described above.**

Comment: Thanks so much for resolving the issue for me.  I made the change and it worked.  I am still hazy on the the whole middleware handling next() thing.  I will check out the references you mentioned.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Express sends `404` HTTP error because the sequence of adding middlewares **does matter**.

As far as you added `404` error sending middleware right after `app.use('/users', users);` middleware, `404` middleware will be executed next - it will throw send an error ( `next(err);` ) to next middleware which catches all errors and sends response. To resolve this issue you need to `.use` error handling middlewares right after all other middlewares:

```
app.post('/dialogflowFulfillment', function (req, res) {
  res.send('POST request to homepage');
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I am unclear about what you said about the middleware routing.  I will have study up on Express.  Thanks again.